# need help to setup internet load-balancing for a small ISP

Tags: router, isp, pfsense

I need some help about the following problems:

1. I want to do load-balancing for two Internet dsl connection from same isp and same speed
2. I need to manage fail over also
3. I want to manage up to 50 user only over wireless using a hotspot

For all these currently I have tried following :

- I first have a mikrotik 3.3 router with [bullet](http://www.wlanparts.com/product/BULLET-M2-HP/Ubiquiti-BULLET-M2-HP-Outdoor-80211n-M2HP.html) m2 hp with a 12dbi omni [antenna](http://www.itchasers.com/store/products/TP-LINK-TL%252dANT2412D-12dBi,-Outdoor-Antenna,-N%252dtype-connector.html)
- I have managed successfully manage 25 users on single connection with no problem but I have more then 30 users and there are problems with bandwidth, so now I have 2 connections and want to load balance them to make the out put just like I have earlier for 25 user.
- For this I have used load balancing in mikrotik router but it was pathetic and gives burst at user end while with single connection with out load balancing it works really fine the only problem is the download rate is gone down when all the users are signed in to mikrotik,
- Then I tried to use pfsense at the back end of mikrotik so that I can load balance it before mikrotik and then give a single in line to mikrotik , again I got same burst out put via bullet m2 hp but this time on lan I have no problem with speed and download rate but I have to get this performance on wireless but it did't solve the problem
- Then I have done some setting in pfsense by making a bridge interface and assigning it to lan interface and defining NAT rules for bridge and then I got some better out put on my tplink wireless indoor router its almost I need on bullet but with bullet I got a bit better performance as I have before this work around, the problem now is sometimes pfsense need to restart as it got unresponsive 2 or 3 times in 24 hrs.

Here I all the story I have gone through and have these question to think

1. There is some problem with bullet m2 hp as after load balancing it gives bursts
2. The load balancing is not done as it has to be ideally and the problem is with my config :(
3. There is some issue with this pair pfsense and mikrotik (may be)
4. I need to change the routing os to other one that can give me both a superb load balancing with a good hotspot config option, (pfsense don't let me authenticate user with both mac address and username password so I can't use it alone for load balancing and user managment )

I am thinking about [zero-shell](http://www.zeroshell.net/eng/) is it a good option for my problem (need help)

Please guide me about this regards.